# jQuery load another page div element into specific div

Tags: jquery, load

I am working around a simple jQuery method to load a div element from another page to mine.

Here is what i found about the "load" jQuery function:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

And here is the code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Projects:</b>
<ol id="new-projects"></ol>

<script>
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "http://api.jquery.com/resources/load.html #projects li" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The code is the same as in the example if the given link above.
I've pasted this code in blank .php file. You can see the result here:
http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/test/

As you can see it sais only "Projects:".

Why it's not working like in the example in jQuery, where is my mistake ?

Comment: Learn to debug your code with the console. You're getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.jquery.com/resources/load.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://beta.sportsdirect.bg' is therefore not allowed access.` See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: So how i can fix it ? I don't know how to debugg

Comment: Did you read the error and the link?

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have a same origin policy. Ergo, you can't load resources from another webpage through jquery simply because it's far too easy to get nailed by a XSS attack that way. Unless the content is on the same domain, this just doesn't work.